# Problems with IMetaDataImport::ResolveTypeRef Method

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, imetadataimport

I have my own debugger for .NET apps that uses [`IMetaDataImport` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230172.aspx)

When I call `ResolveTypeRef` method, I always get `NotImplementedException`.

The definition of `ResolveTypeRef` is like this:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("....")] //a valid GUID
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[CLSCompliant(false)]
public interface IMetaDataImport {
  void ResolveTypeRef(
    [ComAliasName("mdTypeRef")] mdToken tr,
    [ComAliasName("REFIID")] ref Guid riid,
    [ComAliasName("IUnknown**"), Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppIScope,
    [ComAliasName("mdTypeDef*"), Out] out mdToken ptd
  );
  // ... other methods from IMetaDataImport
}
```

The method calling:

```
metadataImport.ResolveTypeRef(typeRefToken, ref metadataImportGuid, out metadataObject, out typeDefToken)
```

Typically, the method should resolve type System.Exception or System.SystemException.

The problem occured when I moved app from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: I wonder if the "ref" keyword should be befor the "riid" parameter. But it doesn't work with or without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uff, I finally get rid of this ... The solution is not call ResolveTypeRef, but create your own method to resolve type:

```
  mdToken ptkResScope;
  uint len;
  metadataImport.GetTypeRefProps(typeRef, out ptkResScope, null, 0, out len);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder((int)len);
  metadataImport.GetTypeRefProps(typeRef, out ptkResScope, sb, len, out len);
  string className = sb.ToString();
  foreach (loadedModule ) {   // this is quite tricky part ...     
    metadataImportForLoadedModule = GetMetaDataImportForModule(loadedModule);
    metadataImportForLoadedModule.FindTypeDefByName(className, mdToken.Nil, out typeDef);
    if ( typeDef.IsNonNil(CorTokenType.mdtTypeDef) ) {
      return typeDef;
      }
    }
```

The idea comes from [David Broman's CLR Profiling API Blog: Metadata Tokens, Run-Time IDs, and Type Loading](https://web.archive.org/web/20190114032248/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davbr/2011/10/17/metadata-tokens-run-time-ids-and-type-loading/) (really good reading if you are interested in MetaDataImport).

Comment: funny, I want to mark this as an answer, but I will be able in 22 hours :)

Comment: Damn, and at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230990(v=vs.110).aspx) there is nothing about this **not implemented exception**! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you actually try and step into the method `ResolveTypeRef`, it seems you actually end up at `SymMethod::GetSourceStartEnd` which is what is returning `E_NOTIMPL`. Furthermore, if you have a look at the vtable in IDA, as far as I can see the method `ResolveTypeRef` doesn't even exist on `IMetaDataImport/2`'s vtable; rather, it is a method on `CordbModule`, however evidently isn't actually exposed in the `ICorDebugModule` interface.

In any case, the conclusion here appears to be that Microsoft's documentation/header files are out of date with the actual implementation